# Make Excel cell display X but compute to Y

Tags: excel, excel-formula

Is this at all possible/recommended? Or do you have to use hidden cells?

Comment: As in `=FUNC(A1)` where the calculation is performed on a value other than `A1`'s? You can use a hidden column - or better a column on a different sheet as its easier to interact with, some more detail may help.

Comment: What are X and Y?  Please provide an example.

Comment: Well, X might be "buyer"/"seller" and Y might be 0/1. The cell values are used in a PRODUCTSUM-formula.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do it with conditional formatting.

There's a good explanation [here on superuser](https://superuser.com/questions/281431/excel-cells-show-text-different-to-the-actual-value)

(This will only be suitable in certain situations)